# Unable to find the object Confirm in Chrome in Testcomplete

Tags: google-chrome, jscript, testcomplete

I am using the Confirm object used for confirmation messages. I want to Click on the OK Button, but it give me an error as:

> Unable to find the object Confirm. See Additional Information for details.

The example for the click confirmation message in Test complete documentation works fine on IExplorer and Firefox but not on Chrome.

The piece of code used is as follows:

```
var Page=Sys.Browser("*").Page("*");
var Travel_Cost_Input = Page.QuerySelector('#service_cost_input');
Travel_Cost_Input.Click();
Page.Wait();
Page.Confirm.Button("OK").Click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try calling using Confirm with parentheses:

```
Page.Confirm().Button("OK").Click();
```

If this does not work, use Object Spy to capture the button object and check its the correct name.